# filter is not working inside angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I want to filter list of object using filter object inside angular controller. But it's give me filtered list. It should return second object.

This is my code sample

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.list=[
  {

    "job_id": 2,
    "description": "Bid for Job 2",
    "price": 115,
    "butler_id": 60,
    "butler_name": "Butler Client 1",
    "service_price": 500,
    "material_price": 900,
    "date_created": "23 Apr 1993"
  },
  {

    "job_id": 2,
    "description": "sfcs",
    "price": 555,
    "butler_id": 70,
    "butler_name": "Butler Client 2",
    "service_price": 666,
    "material_price": 666,
    "date_created": "23 Apr 1993"
  }
];

  $scope.filter ={"butler_name":"","service_price":"","material_price":"6","price":"","created_date":"","description":""};

 var getFiltered = $filter('filter')($scope.list, $scope.filter);
  $scope.filteredBids = getFiltered;

});
```

[**Plunker link**](https://plnkr.co/edit/FHiJkvqVabgxTa3zyg5Y?p=preview)

Comment: Which filter you wanted to apply? currently is applied over almost all properties..

Comment: Your plunker actually works. e.g: `$scope.filter = {butler_name: 'Butler Client 1'};`

Comment: as you can see, in filter object, some property is empty, so if property is empty then filter should not apply on that property

Comment: @mostruash: no, I don't want to pass object name one by one, I want to pass all filter as object

Comment: `$scope.filter = {butler_name: 'Butler Client 1', job_id: 2};` works too. You can pass all of them together. Your problem might be that you want to chain OR filter properties, but angular's filter chain ANDs them.

Comment: @mostruash: yes. you got it. and also I want if any property is empty then it should not be consider in filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing all property in filter, and Angular consider AND, so you are not getting any result.

You have to create properties according to your filter.

```
 var filterParams = {};
        if ($scope.filter.butler_name.trim() !== "") {
            filterParams.butler_name = $scope.filter.butler_name;
        }
        if ($scope.filter.service_price.trim() !== "") {
            filterParams.service_price = $scope.filter.service_price;
        }
        if ($scope.filter.material_price.trim() !== "") {
            filterParams.material_price = $scope.filter.material_price;
        }
        if ($scope.filter.price.trim() !== "") {
            filterParams.price = $scope.filter.price;
        }
        if ($scope.filter.created_date.trim() !== "") {
            filterParams.created_date = $scope.filter.created_date;
        }
        if ($scope.filter.description.trim() !== "") {
            filterParams.description = $scope.filter.description;
        }
        var getFiltered = $filter('filter')($scope.list, filterParams);
        $scope.filteredBids = getFiltered;
```

[Updated link](https://plnkr.co/edit/FHiJkvqVabgxTa3zyg5Y?p=preview)